# Can't display images webserver python

Tags: python, html, css, sockets, webserver

I am trying to display text/html/css/images on my browser with a python web server.
But only the css/text/html is working. Anyone knows why the images are not showing?

Here is my code :

```
import urlparse

from socket import *

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

port = 8080

s.bind(('', port))
s.listen(1)

#Fill in end

while True:
client, addr = s.accept()

try:
    data = client.recv(1024)
    filename = data.split()[1]

    file = open(filename[1:])

    outputdata = file.read()

    client.send('\nHTTP / 1.x200OK\n')

    for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
        client.send(outputdata[i])

    client.close()

except IOError:
    client.send('\n404 File Not Found\n')

    client.close()

s.close()
```

Thank you!

Comment: could be a bunch of things, is the path to the images valid? do you have the html displaying the image default to something so you know if the problem is there?

Comment: why are you sending the result byte by byte? `Content-Type` is needed for images.

Comment: Try to talk HTTP instead of some strange protocol which resembles HTTP only in very few ways.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that you're not setting the right HTTP headers (Content-Type, Content-Length, etc). Instead of re-implementing this stuff from scratch, why not use one of the many Python web frameworks that will take care of all this for you?

Comment: I already did this before with python's implemented class httpserver. But I wanted to do everything myself now.

Comment: Do I need to set the contentlength/type in the outputdata?